# Jenkins service does not start with SDKMan Java on Oracle Linux

Tags: linux, jenkins, service, installation

I have installed [SDKMan](https://sdkman.io) on my Oracle Linux 6.9 server. And then installed Java and Jenkins. I created symlinks for `/usr/bin/java` and `/usr/bin/javac`.

When I try starting the Jenkins service: `sudo service jenkins start`

I get error saying: `Starting Jenkins bash: /usr/bin/java: Permission denied`

This is the executable:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 54 Dec  8 00:07 /usr/bin/java -> /home/user/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin/java
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK solved this now. I had to change the `JENKINS_USER` (in `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins`) from `jenkins` to `root` in my case. As per the instructions [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Red+Hat+distributions) changing the user should be accompanied with changing ownership of `/var/lib/jenkins`, `/var/log/jenkins`, `/var/cache/jenkins` (which in my case was already `root`).